# Can I have Post Types under other Post Types in Admin menu?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu, hierarchical

Lets say I have created two custom post types `A` and `B`. Those post types are displayed in the Admin menu one after another. (After `Posts` for example)

Is there a way to display `B` under `A`?

The only similar behavior I am aware of is to assign Taxonomies to Post Types. This forces the first to be displayed under the second. I am looking for a way to do this using custom post types.

It's like having relationships across post types.

*I am managing post types and taxonomies using the excellent `GD CPT Tools` plugin.
Wordpress 3.4.2*

Comment: Yes, if you are OK with using a (highly rated) [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-types-order/)!

Comment: Been searching about an hour for something like this :p

Comment: then there is your answer!

Comment: I think this does something else than my question. This allows posts (of whatever post-type) to be reordered. What I am looking is a way to do this within post types.

Comment: This is likely to be the answer. Haven't test it yet
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8373533/245495

Answer (score 11):

Yes, this capability is available with [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), via the `show_in_menu` argument, but whether or not the particular plugin you are using supports this I don't know.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa70679_custom_types' );

function wpa70679_custom_types() {

    register_post_type( 'parent_type',
        array(
            'public' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Parent post type'
            )
        )
    );

    register_post_type( 'child_type',
        array(
            'public' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=parent_type',
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Child post type'
            )
        )
    );

}
```

[image: Results]