# Add management screens to post type

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I am looking to build a theme that has an integrated resume, using custom post types.  I have had a look at [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70679/can-i-have-post-types-under-other-post-types-in-admin-menu) with regards to inserting post types within post types in the admin menu.  The structure that I am planning is:

Resume

- View Employment
- Add Employment
- View Qualifications
- Add Qualification
- View Memberships
- Add Membership
- Options

How would I insert links to the appropriate post management screen in the menu?

**[EDIT]**

I have tried to create this in my local site, and have noticed that the menu only displays the post management page, not the editor (the opposite of what I assumed).  I would like both to be displayed.  Is this possible?

Comment: that's shown in the WSE answer I posted earlier, but my understanding is that will only display the post editor, not the post manager. Unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Well, had you tried it? :) Going by description this seems to be a duplicate of that thread.

Comment: Just updated the post. I was slightly off: it displays the management menu, not the editor as first thought, but I do still want both to be displayed if that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is I have found a solution.  The (kind of) bad news is that the menu has to be created manually.  It would use a combination of the [add_menu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) and [add_submenu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) functions.  The codex pages have the format for the functions.

The menu would be

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );

function register_my_custom_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page('My Custom Page', 'My Custom Page', 'manage_options', 'my-top-level-slug', '', '', 28);
    add_submenu_page( 'my-top-level-slug', 'My Custom Page', 'My Custom Page', 'manage_options', 'my-top-level-slug');
    add_submenu_page( 'my-top-level-slug', 'My Custom Submenu Page', 'My Custom Submenu Page', 'manage_options', 'my-secondary-slug');
}
```

Then, in the custom post type, the `'show_in_menu'` variable would be set to `false` for each custom post type and the slugs posted into the appropriate variables in the function.